# one class under another class on intellij?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I made a commit then I did a reset ^hard to undo the commit, then my repository become  a mess.

Now it's almost repaired, one thing I did was rename a .java because it was in lower case, but I cant pull it again from github, even it's on gihub.

and the project explorer shows this:

[image]

any Ideas what this means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that you have a file `contactPDFView.java`, which contains definition for the class `ContactPDFView`.

Rename the file to `ContactPDFView.java`